# Display a key from unserialized data field

Tags: 7, views

I really don't understand how the "User: Data" field works. Couldn't find any documentation of this.

I want to set the Display format to "A certain key" to output the identifier value from this serialized data (relevant snippet):

```
a:1:{s:10:"hybridauth";a:26:{s:10:"identifier";s:17:"76561198181833179";
```

When I enter identifier as key, I only get this notice and no output.

> Notice: Undefined index: identifier in views_handler_field_serialized->render() (line 60 of www/htdocs/****/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_serialized.inc).

What do I have to enter in the "Which key should be displayed" field exactly, to display the identifier value?

Comment: "When I enter identifier as key" - show us your code, we can't tell you what's wrong with it if we can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Global PHP field and put the following code in output value to get the **identifier** field value.

```
<?php 
 $result = unserialize($row->data); 
 print $result['identifier'];
?>
```

**Note : You should exclude Data field from display.**

Since you very cautious in not using PHP, did you try the following option, change the **ckeditor_skin to identifier**. But it will produce the output as **76561198181833179['identifier'].**

[image]

Comment: I wanted to avoid PHP in views. I've heard it's bad for performance and is insecure. But when nobody can help me with the "User: Data"-field, I'll fall back to this option. Thanks.

Comment: I already tried this. It outputs nothing and gives me this notice as stated above: _Notice: Undefined index: identifier in views_handler_field_serialized->render() (line 60 of /www/htdocs/*drupalsite*/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_serialized.inc)._

Answer (score -1):

Try %ckeditor_skin in the field 'Which key should be displayed'.

If the error message

> Notice: Undefined index: identifier in views_handler_field_serialized-render() (line 60 of /www/htdocs/*drupalsite*/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_se‌​rialized.inc).

still exists but the number of the error messages is less than before, try to change the code

```
return check_plain($value[$this->options['key']])
```

to:

```
if (!empty($value[$this->options['key']])) { 
  return check_plain($value[$this->options['key']]);
}
```

in line 60 of the module file to avoid the error message.

Comment: You shouldn't hack core or contributed modules!